# How to unlock (re-load current state) in optimistic locking?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have an entity with optimistic locking:

```java
@Version
private Integer version;
```

I do a get request by id which performs a `findById`
in the backend. I use the id to perform an update
using PUT method which performs a `save` in the backend.
After that I do the get again to get the modified object back:
After that I try to update it again and get:

```
{
    "timestamp": {
        "nano": 305933000,
        "epochSecond": 1638524115
    },
    "status": 500,
    "error": [],
    "type": "ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException",
    "path": "uri=/rooms/",
    "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

Why do I get that error? The first update transaction should be done, shouldnt it?
How can I unlock the entity?

I do not use `EntityManger`. I use `JpaRepsoitory` with `save` method.

**EDIT**

If I provide the version as an attribute in the get call and
set the version into the entity which im saving it works.

Is this the way you usually do it? That the client has to
provide the latest version of the entity which should get updated?

Comment: If you get an optimistic locking failure, that means the object that you tried to update wasn't up-to-date when you edited it. In other words: after an update, you need to re-load the current state, edit it, then you can update again. You can't just blindly update twice, because there's no guarantee that no one else edited in between. That's exactly what optimistic locking is trying to avoid. Optimistic locking is a fancy way of saying "update the version on each save, throw an exception if someone is trying to do an update with an object that doesn't have the latest version".

Comment: Yes, I got that. But how can I re-load the current state?

Comment: load-by-id? I don't know. How did you load it in the first place?

Comment: And that is exactly what I do. I do `findById` to get the id of the entity. After that I update it and perform `save`. After that I do again `findById`. But if I do a `save` after that I get the exception

Comment: I fear you'll need to provide a [mre] for this.

Comment: You are using your copy of the object you passed to save, not the one returned from JPA merge. JPA's merge will update the version value in the object it manages (and returned from JPA merge calls) for you, making it safe to reuse - reflecting the current state in the DB once done, which is what save should be returning. Otherwise, you must call findById again after the save call and the transaction commits to get the managed instance/state from the DB.

Comment: Or - what is the value of the version field when you call "After that I do the get again to get the modified object back"? That should be the value from the DB, the latest value after your last save call. If it isn't, you have an issue somewhere else. That value then needs to be used and used in the object on your next update call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't going to get the exception until the save is executed in the database, and your save doesn't happen immediately,  remember it uses transactional write-behind.

If your flush mode is AUTO, which is the default for JPA, then the save doesn't get pushed to the database until your second findById, that counts as running a query so any updates have to be flushed first. Once the update executes, the version comparison happens, JPA realizes no row was updated and it throws the optimistic locking exception.

BTW when you say you're not using an EntityManager: you're not using one directly but there is still one involved, the JPA repository is using one. All this stuff of stashing updates and deciding when to push them is done by an EntityManager. It also caches the result of running queries.

When you say current state, there are several states. There is the state of the entity manager, then there's the state of the transaction in progress, then there is the state of the database with committed changes. The EntityManager uses the flush mode to decide when to sync up its own 1st level cache state with the transaction in progress.

And yes you have to give the entity being updated the latest version number, that is what is getting compared.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!